# How to set a CSV file read-only for direct access and edit only through a Python UI?

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a CSV file in a server where server users should not be able to manipulate the file. It should be read only. The only way users can add new information is through a Python UI that I created. What approach can I take it to create this file?

Comment: The UI python app may change the attribute of the file using [os.chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod). Opening the app, you remove the read-only attribute. Before closing the app, set read-only attribute back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file with rw permissions for the owner and r permissions for all others, then run the python GUI under the user id of the file owner.

```
$ touch file.csv
$ chmod 644 file.csv
```

(Assuming you run on a Unix-like operating system).

Comment: How can I run the python GUI under the owner user id? I made the GUI an executable using pyinstaller to distribute to the clients.